# Get apache logs as csv file

Tags: apache

Is there a way to save all apache logs as CSV file?

```
access.log->access_log.csv
error.log->error_log.csv
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a [custom log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) to make Apache log directly into a comma-separated format.

You may have to fiddle with this for a while to find the right way. For example, you will probably want to use `"` or `'` as field delimiters to prevent commas inside the field values from breaking your CSV.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the problem that you want to look at logfiles written in the past, or logfiles from apache servers that you don't have access to the config files, or if you for some other reason don't want to change the logfile format:

I've written a [little linux shell sed script](http://koega.no-ip.org/mediawiki/index.php/Apache_logfiles_to_csv) that transforms the default apache logfiles into a format that can be read by libre office calc:

```
#!/bin/bash

#reformat apache's access logs, so that they can be interpreted as csv files, 
# with space as column delimiter and double quotes to bind together things
# that contain spaces but represent single columns.

# 1)  add a doublequote at the begining of the line. first column is the ip adress. 
#     ip-adresses that have 3 digits in every group but the first could be interpreted as numbers 
#     with the dots marking groups of thousands.

# 2a) end the ip-adress with quotes
# 2b) surround the second (to me unknown) column thats always just "-" and the
#     third column which is the username with quotes
# 2c) reformat the date from "[09/Jul/2012:11:17:47" to "09.Jul 2012 11:17:47"

# 3)  remove the string "+0200]" (replace it with doublequotes to end the date column)

# 4)  the string that contains the command (5th column) sometimes contains string representation 
#     of binary rubish. thats no problem as long as this does not contain a doublequote which 
#     will mess up the column zoning. According to my web searches, csv columns should allow to 
#     contain doublequotes if they are escaped with a backslash. Although this is the case with
#     these problematic strings, Libre Office does not accept it that way. therefore we escape every 
#     doublequote with a doubleqoute, which is the other valid option according to csv specifications,
#     and libre office does accept that one. More technical: we replace every doublequote that does
#     neither have a space or another doublequote before it, neither after it, with two doublequotes.

sed \
-e 's/^/"/' \
-e 's/ \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/\([a-zA-Z]\{1,3\}\)\/\([0-9]\{1,4\}\):/" "\1" "\2" "\3.\4 \5 /' \
-e 's/ +0200\] /" /' \
-e 's/\([^" ]\)"\([^" ]\)/\1""\2/g'
```

Comment: Not quite perfect (it doesn't add commas between the fields), but this got me close.

Comment: well, open office will take any seperator you like, and I used a space here. some csv files have a comma (,) some have a semicolon (;) it's not standardised.

Comment: Any chance you have a version that handles the default apache error.log files?

Comment: no, I've never needed it. But to me it looks like its of a much simpler format, it should be quite easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is really just a modification of @kaefert's answer. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it but this works great.

```
alias aplogcsv="sed -e 's/^/\"/' \
                -e 's/:\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\",\"\1\2\3\4/' \
                -e 's/ \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/\([a-zA-Z]\{1,3\}\)\/\([0-9]\{1,4\}\):/\",\"\1\" \"\2\" \"\3 \4 \5\",\" /' \
                -e 's/ \([0-9]\{1,2\}\):\([0-9]\{1,2\}\):\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)/\1:\2:\3/' \
                -e 's/ $(date +%z)\] /\",/' \
                -e 's/\"GET /\"GET\",\"/g' \
                -e 's/\"POST /\"POST\",\"/g' \
                -e 's/ HTTP\/1.1\" \([0-9]\{1,3\}\) \([0-9]\{1,4\}\) /\",\"HTTP\/1.1\",\1,\2,/' \
                -e 's/\"-\" //g'"
```

Then I use it like this:

```
aplogcsv access.log > ~/access.log.csv
```

but it's also easy to use like this:

```
grep "25/Jan/2019" access.log | aplogcsv > ~/20190125.access.log.csv
```

Comment: A few issues with this that I've observed:

1. if the response size is  > 9999 bytes this doesn't work as expected
2. having a replacement for `-0700` makes it specific to one time zone

Comment: @malcomio Are you sure the 9999 bytes isn't a limitation in your system. I've never had an issue with that. As far as the timezone offset, I've updated my answer to use a variable in place of that -0700 to prevent timezone issues.

Comment: pretty sure it's because the regex has `\{1,4\}` - i.e. limited to 4 characters

Comment: I've adapted this into a script and pushed it to https://github.com/malcomio/log-parsers/blob/main/apache-access.sh