# One liner for apache error logs to store as csv file

Tags: bash, perl, csv

I would like to convert the error logs lookinglike this:

```
[ Message time ]  [Message Type] [IP Address] PHP Errpr Type: Some Message with comma in it
```

Into something like this so that I can read it using any spreadsheet software:

```
Message Time,Message Type,IP Address,PHP Errpr Type,Some Message with comma in it
```

I have seen [Get apache logs as csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707865/get-apache-logs-as-csv-file), [Apache-Access-Log-to-CSV-Converter](https://github.com/mboynes/Apache-Access-Log-to-CSV-Converter/blob/master/apache_log_to_csv_converter.php)
 and [Load Testing with JMeter: Part 3 - Replaying Apache Logs](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/load-testing-jmeter-part-3-replaying-apache-logs/). which don't help with my case.

I wrote a Bash script which works but it takes a hell lot of time for a file with 600,000 lines in it.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

rm -fv final_file
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat error_log | tr '[]' '"'`
do
        MSG_MESSAGE="`echo $i|awk -F']' '{print $NF}'`"
        MSG_ERROR_TYPE="`echo $MSG_MESSAGE| awk -F':' '{print $1}'`"
        MSG_DEBUG_MESSGE="`echo $MSG_MESSAGE|cut -d':' -f2-|tr ',' '.'`"
        MSG_DATE="`echo $i|awk -F']' '{print $1}'| cut -d'[' -f2`"
        MSG_TYPE="`echo $i|awk -F']' '{print $2}'| cut -d'[' -f2`"
        MSG_CLIENT="`echo $i|awk -F']' '{print $3}'| cut -d'[' -f2`"
        echo "$MSG_DATE~$MSG_TYPE~$MSG_CLIENT~$MSG_ERROR_TYPE~$MSG_DEBUG_MESSGE" >> final_file
done
unset IFS
```

Bash or Perl, anything is fine, as long as it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled by `sed` easily:

```
sed -r 's/^\[([^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]\s*([^:]*):\s*/\1,\2,\3,\4,/' file
           ^^^^^^^^^^                                         ^^
               |______________________________________________|
```

It is a matter of catching blocks and printing them back

#### Test

```
$ cat a
[ Message time ]  [Message Type] [IP Address] PHP Errpr Type: Some Message with comma in it
$ sed -r 's/^\[([^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]\s*([^:]*):\s*/\1,\2,\3,\4,/' a
 Message time ,Message Type,IP Address,PHP Errpr Type,Some Message with comma in it
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification on fedorqui's answer is

```
sed -r -e 's/([^]]*)$/"\1"/'  -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]/,/g' input
```

Same thing essentially, but will work with an arbitrary number of [bracketed] items and is easier to read - not sure which will be quicker though if your files are huge.